# First time Play Framework 2.2.2 with java error

Tags: playframework, frameworks, playframework-2.0

I just run simple command after install Play Framework latest version 2.2.2
I install on C:\play-2.2.2 and set PATH already, Open command line in Win 7 and type play and got following error, Please let me know what wrong? and how can I fix it?

```
C:\>play
Getting org.fusesource.jansi jansi 1.11 ...
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-jansi
        confs: [default]
        1 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (111kB/20ms)
Getting com.typesafe.play console_2.10 2.2.2 ...
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-app
        confs: [default]
        6 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (2012kB/37ms)
Getting Scala 2.10.3 (for console)...
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-scala
        confs: [default]
        5 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (24447kB/61ms)
[ERROR] Terminal initialization failed; falling back to unsupported
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class     org.fusesource.jansi.internal.Kernel32
        at     org.fusesource.jansi.internal.WindowsSupport.getConsoleMode(WindowsSupport.java:50)
        at jline.WindowsTerminal.getConsoleMode(WindowsTerminal.java:177)
        at jline.WindowsTerminal.init(WindowsTerminal.java:80)
        at jline.TerminalFactory.create(TerminalFactory.java:101)
        at jline.TerminalFactory.get(TerminalFactory.java:159)
        at jline.console.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:227)
        at jline.console.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:219)
        at jline.console.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:207)
        at play.console.Console$.<init>(Console.scala:14)
        at play.console.Console$.<clinit>(Console.scala)
        at play.console.Console.run(Console.scala:201)
        at play.console.Console.run(Console.scala:198)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:57)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:77)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:57)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:45)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:65)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:32)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:21)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)

       _
 _ __ | | __ _ _  _
| '_ \| |/ _' | || |
|  __/|_|\____|\__ /
|_|            |__/

play 2.2.2 built with Scala 2.10.3 (running Java 1.8.0), http://www.playframework.com

This is not a play application!

Use `play new` to create a new Play application in the current directory,
or go to an existing application and launch the development console using `play`.

You can also browse the complete documentation at http://www.playframework.com.

java.lang.NullPointerException
        at jline.internal.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:23)
        at jline.internal.ShutdownHooks.remove(ShutdownHooks.java:89)
        at jline.TerminalSupport.restore(TerminalSupport.java:56)
        at play.console.Console$.run(Console.scala:181)
        at play.console.Console.run(Console.scala:201)
        at play.console.Console.run(Console.scala:198)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:57)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:77)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:57)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:45)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:65)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:32)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:21)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Error during sbt execution: java.lang.NullPointerException

C:\>
```

Comment: You are using Java 8? I think it is not supported yet, in 2.2.2..

Comment: Play 2.2.2 works just fine with Java 8. Try running "play new" to create a new application, as the output suggests.